# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier: Javascript with Cef3

Tags: javascript, cefsharp

I am using a CEF3 based browser which offers the .Eval(Javascript) method.

I would like to include ad blocking in my app.

I found the following code [here](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1413):

```
string adblock = "function C(d,o){v=d.createElement('div');o.parentNode.replaceChild(v,o);}function A(d){for(j=0;t=[", Interaction.IIf(browser.Address.Contains("youtube.com"), "'iframe','marquee'", "'iframe','embed','marquee'")), "][j];++j){o=d.getElementsByTagName(t);for(i=o.length-1;i>=0;i--)C(d,o[i]);}g=d.images;for(k=g.length-1;k>=0;k--)if({'21x21':1,'48x48':1,'60x468':1,'88x31':1,'88x33':1,'88x62':1,'90x30':1,'90x32':1,'90x90':1,'100x30':1,'100x37':1,'100x45':1,'100x50':1,'100x70':1,'100x100':1,'100x275':1,'110x50':1,'110x55':1,'110x60':1,'110x110':1,'120x30':1,'120x60':1,'120x80':1,'120x90':1,'120x120':1,'120x163':1,'120x181':1,'120x234':1,'120x240':1,'120x300':1,'120x400':1,'120x410':1,'120x500':1,'120x600':1,'120x800':1,'125x40':1,'125x60':1,'125x65':1,'125x72':1,'125x80':1,'125x125':1,'125x170':1,'125x250':1,'125x255':1,'125x300':1,'125x350':1,'125x400':1,'125x600':1,'125x800':1,'126x110':1,'130x60':1,'130x65':1,'130x158':1,'130x200':1,'132x70':1,'140x55':1,'140x350':1,'145x145':1,'146x60':1,'150x26':1,'150x60':1,'150x90':1,'150x100':1,'150x150':1,'155x275':1,'155x470':1,'160x80':1,'160x126':1,'160x600':1,'180x30':1,'180x66':1,'180x132':1,'180x150':1,'194x165':1,'200x60':1,'220x100':1,'225x70':1,'230x30':1,'230x33':1,'230x60':1,'234x60':1,'234x68':1,'240x80':1,'240x300':1,'250x250':1,'275x60':1,'280x280':1,'300x60':1,'300x100':1,'300x250':1,'320x50':1,'320x70':1,'336x280':1,'350x300':1,'350x850':1,'360x300':1,'380x112':1,'380x250':1,'392x72':1,'400x40':1,'400x50':1,'425x600':1,'430x225':1,'440x40':1,'464x62':1,'468x16':1,'468x60':1,'468x76':1,'468x120':1,'468x248':1,'470x60':1,'480x400':1,'486x60':1,'545x90':1,'550x5':1,'600x30':1,'720x90':1,'720x300':1,'725x90':1,'728x90':1,'734x96':1,'745x90':1,'750x25':1,'750x100':1,'750x150':1,'850x120':1}[g[k].width+'x'+g[k].height])C(d,g[k]);}A(document);for(f=0;z=frames[f];++f)A(z.document)";
```

browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(adblock);

I receive the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier".
I find the code really hard to read.

Does anybody see the error?

Thank you!

Comment: Try run the code through something like https://unminify.com/ to make it more readable.

Comment: @amaitland Thank you, but it doesn't work. unminify.com marks the code red. So I guess there is something wrong even in the formatting. But my JS experience is too limited to solve / see the error.